# Reading from txt file in Swift 3

Tags: swift, file, swift3

I want to know how to read from a txt file and print out specific parts of the file?

For example, "test.txt" will contain:

'''Jason 16 male self programing

Josh 15 male friend art'''

So I am looking for a way to print each word and line separately. Such as only printing:

"Jason"

"Jason is 16"

"Josh likes art"

This is what I got so far from searching around

```
if let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "test", ofType: "txt")
    {
        do
        {
            let contents = try String(contentsOfFile: filepath)
            print(contents[0])

        }
        catch
        {
            // contents could not be loaded
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // example.txt not found!
    }
```

Thank you for your support.

Comment: If you want to access the words separately consider to use a property list (a special kind of XML) rather than a plain text file.

Comment: hmm, maybe that could also work. But I really want to store the text in a txt file, because I will actually have a lot of information to put inside the txt file. Each line having information that is related, then having 200+ lines of txt.

Comment: Doesn't work on Linux

Answer (score 5):

Once you have read your file into `contents` you can break it into lines and words with code like:

```
let lines = contents.components(separatedBy: "\n")
for line in lines {
    let words = line.components(separatedBy: " ")
    print("\(words[0]) is \(words[1]) and likes \(words[4])")
}
```

Comment: String has a method called enumerateSubstrings with options .byLines or .byWords exactly for this purpose