# Bundle.main.path(forResource:ofType:inDirectory:) returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, macos, file, swift3

Try not to laugh or cry -- I'm just getting back into coding after 20 years out...
I've spent more than 4 hours looking at references and trying code snippets to get Bundle.main.path to open my text file so I can read in data for my app (my next step is to appropriately parse it).

```
if let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "newTest", ofType: "txt")
{
    do
    {
        let contents = try String(contentsOfFile: filepath)
        print(contents)

    }
    catch
    {
        print("Contents could not be loaded.")
    }
}
else
{
    print("newTest.txt not found.")
}
```

The result is: "newTest.txt not found." regardless of how I try to drag&drop the file into the project, create the file inside Xcode or use the File -> Add Files to ... menu item.

Comment: let path : String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "charlie", ofType: "txt")!
 let url : URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548771/swift-how-do-i-get-the-file-path-inside-a-folder/34548888?s=2|1.1932#34548888

Comment: @LeoDabus my problem is similar to [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40822170/reading-from-txt-file-in-swift-3[/link] (which you also commented on) and also gives me the same error.

Comment: Brother your problem solve or not ?

Comment: No, same error. :.(...

Comment: IN my code which line you got error mention in my answer so i can help you

Comment: "let content = try String(..." gives the same error. I dragged & dropped my file into the project at the same level as the main.swift and made sure the 'Create Folder References' and 'Add to targets:' were checked.

Comment: let content = try String(contentsOfFile:path!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)  use this line

Comment: That's exactly what I did use and get the same error.

Comment: are you using xcode 8.1 right ?

Comment: Currently using: Xcode 8.2.1

Comment: @ZakariusJayPoggenpohl just remove your code and use my code and see any error occure or not ?

Comment: I just tried... only changed the file name to "testFile" (instead of your code's "demo") and I got the original error.

Comment: in my code i dont think so that kind of error you just clean your project and create again new .txt file and add in it again in your project and run my code .

Answer (score 293):

The issue is that the file isn't being copied to your app bundle. To fix it:

- Click your project
- Click your target
- Select Build Phases
- Expand Copy Bundle Resources
- Click '+' and select your file.

Comment: I added the file to "Copy Bundle Resources" however I also found it in my "Compile Sources" list which is because it was originally a swift file until I changed the extension.  But changing the extension didn't remove it from "Compile Sources".  So I pulled it out, ran it and worked like a charm.

Comment: This worked for me when nothing else worked. Why would a file I drop into Xcode not automatically show up under "Copy Bundle Resources"???

Comment: @Trev14 makes no sense that this doesn't happen automatically

Comment: Insane, lost a couple of hours on this when I forgot this "trick" on checking what's being added to the app bundle. The problem was I was using another IDE where I added the file and that IDE didn't edit the .pbxproj, thus I didn't have my resource in the app bundle

Comment: Didn't work.  Assets.xcassets was already there anyway.  The only solution that works is to add the file to the list of project files, which is really messy.  Essentially, you have to create your OWN assets folder-- totally annoying. Be sure to check "Create Groups" and "Add to Target" when you drag your file into the project.

Answer (score 46):

Double check the `Options` in the `add files` menu when adding the file. The target in `Add to targets` must be ticked to add it to the bundle:

[image]

In case you are actually in another bundle (test for instance), use:

```
guard let fileURL = Bundle(for: type(of: self)).url(forResource: fileName withExtension:"txt") else {
        fatalError("File not found")
}
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. I had a json file inside a test target.

Answer (score 37):

Click on your file on your navigation panel and open the Right Panel/ Property Inspector.

[image]

[Ensure that you add to target membership](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Z1wq.png)

Comment: For anyone else that see this and this is the solution for you as it was for me, you have to do this anytime the file gets replaced with a new version.

Answer (score 14):

It's crazy how much time such a simple problem can cost.

Some answers here helped me but I always tried:

```
Bundle.main.url(forResource: selectedTitle, withExtension: "mp3")
```

For some reason that doesn't work, but getting the path and translating it to a URL afterwards works:

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: selectedTitle, ofType: "mp3")
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
```

Comment: what im confused with is that, i actually did create new file. then copied the contents, so it should be there. instead, it's not found in the build phases bundle resources. i had to add it manually, but it still doesnt work. it only worked after i dragged the file to the project and that dialog showed up to transfer the file.

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 3.0**

```
let fileNmae = "demo"
        
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: "txt")
    do {
        let content = try String(contentsOfFile:path!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        print(content)
    } catch {
        print("nil")
    }
```

**SWift 2.0**

```
do{
      if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("YOURTXTFILENAME", ofType: "txt"){
             let data = try String(contentsOfFile:path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
             let myStrings = data.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet())
              print(myStrings)
       }
  } catch let err as NSError {
            //do sth with Error
            print(err)
  }
```

**Output :**

```
Hello Hems
Good Morning
I m here for you dude.
Happy Coding.
```

Comment: @LeoDabus wait i just convert this code in swift 3.0

Comment: I really appreciate your try to help, but I get the following error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: which line ? @ZakariusJayPoggenpohl

Answer (score 6):

This was helpful for me: [xcode - copy a folder structure into my app bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9551237/xcode-copy-a-folder-structure-into-my-app-bundle)

Mark "create folder references" option when you create assets in nested folders.

Then find path to the file like this:

```
let path = Bundle(for: type(of : self)).path(forResource: "some_folder_a/some_folder_b/response.json", ofType: nil)
```

Answer (score 6):

The answer is simply to not use Assets.xcassets to store your audio file,
and add your audio file, ie) BeTheFirstAudio.m4a (made with QuickTime), directly to the PROJECT NAVIGATOR (circled, pink) list of files (photo 1)

[image]

WARNING!  Be sure to check the "CREATE GROUPS" and "ADD TO TARGETS" checkboxes when the pop-up appears after dragging your audio file from your Finder window.

[image]

After that, your code should work to play the audio (including .m4a extensions from QuickTime)

```
 import AVFoundation

 class AudioPlayer: NSObject {


     private var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!

     override init() {
         super.init()
    
         // get URL for the default audio
         let audioURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "BeTheFirstAudio", withExtension: "m4a")

         audioPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioURL!)
     }
```

Apple engineers should be ashamed that this problem is even a question in StackOverflow; developers should be able to add the audio file to Assets.xcassets and Bundle.main.url should be able to find it.  The fact that this simple concept is difficult has probably cost a lot of time for developers. Attention @Apple

Answer (score 4):

Ah, so just found myself dealing with the exact same problem as the OP.

The problem is that the solutions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41777078/4041795) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34548888/4041795) do not work when the code is being executed in a playground, since the `Options` menu of `add files` looks different for it does not show the `Add to targets` field:

[image]

When inside a `.playground` file, instead press the `Hide or show the Navigator` button on the top-right of your Xcode window (visual impression)--> [image]

Then, once the Navigator folds open on the left-side of the Xcode window, simply drag & drop your file to the `Resources` directory of your playground.

If your setup looks anything like the following you should be ok:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This helped me, as I was testing some code in the Playground (part of a larger project).

Answer (score 4):

Same problem, slightly different situation & solution. I'm following a tutorial that said to use the following code:

```
    // Start the background music:
    if let musicPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource:
        "Sound/BackgroundMusic.m4a", ofType: nil) {
        print("SHOULD HEAR MUSIC NOW")
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: musicPath)

        do {
            musicPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            musicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
            musicPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            musicPlayer.play()
        }
        catch { print("Couldn't load music file") }
    }
}
```

I had the same issue as others but none of the solutions fixed the issue. After experimenting, all I did was remove **Sound** from the path in the following call and everything worked:

```
Bundle.main.path(forResource: "BackgroundMusic.m4a", ofType: nil)
```

It would seem that the tutorial was in error by telling me to include **Sound** in the path.

Answer (score 3):

I added `file.txt` to my project and it was automatically added to the `Copy Bundle Files` of my project. For me, I had to remove the extension from the `forResource` and it worked.

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "file", ofType: "txt") // not forResource: "file.txt"
```

Answer (score 2):

### Worth to mention

If you are running unit test or ui test, use their bundle id. Because they are not using main bundle, so you would never find your file by calling `Bundle.main.path(forResource: "newTest", ofType: "txt")`.

Use your test target bundle id. In my case I'm trying to read data from a CSV file. Replace `TestReadFileUITests` with your class name which extends from `XCTestCase`.

Here is the actual bundle id used when I run a UI test case. You could see it is not from main bundle.

```
(lldb) po testBundle
NSBundle </Users/zhouhaibo/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/448D1FCB-8311-4D3F-BEEF-934052C3470F/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/905C2326-8313-410F-9DC2-9D84B9C6D757/TestReadFileUITests-Runner.app/PlugIns/TestReadFileUITests.xctest> (loaded)

(lldb) po filePath
"/Users/zhouhaibo/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/448D1FCB-8311-4D3F-BEEF-934052C3470F/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/905C2326-8313-410F-9DC2-9D84B9C6D757/TestReadFileUITests-Runner.app/PlugIns/TestReadFileUITests.xctest/Patients_2022-09-02.csv"
```

```
let testBundle = Bundle(for: TestReadFileUITests.self)
guard let filePath = testBundle.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: fileType) else {
    print("CSV file not found.")
    return [:]
}
```

```
class TestReadFileUITests: XCTestCase {

    func testDemo() {
        let _ = DataManager.readData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My problem was in one module, created with Cocoapods. Every pod install/update, the files (json files) were there in the project, but never were find inside the Bundle. After pod install/update, I removed (deleted references) the files and add again to the project.

Always pay attention to target where you add the files.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed a similar problem by moving my files from **Assets** catalog to a regular folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't want the `inDirectory:` method. Try this instead:

```
if let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "newTest", ofType: "txt") {
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **R.swift** try this:

I was still having issues specially with a plist file that got changed during build times and since my project is using R.swift I changed the code to be

```
Bundle.main.path(forResource: R.file.myplistfile)
```

and that worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I was throwing a nil with this

```
let myPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Terms", ofType: "json")
```

I had named my file "Terms.JSON" When I realized it should be "Terms.json". that fixed the issue.