# Bundle.main.path(forResource:ofType:inDirectory:) returns nil when app name contains "space"

Tags: ios, swift3

Why the `Bundle.main.path(forResource: "testFile", ofType: "rtf")` returns nil when the app's name has space? anyone encounter this? and perhaps able to fixed? The error doesn't occur if I remove the "space" in the app's name.

When I print the path the result is this `/Users/<user>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/915D4A93-D812-4180-A49E-6BFA3BD77986/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/8623072B-7528-463C-971F-ECD1FB89BDDB/Test Application.app/testFile.rtf` as you may notice the app's name "Test Application.app" has space on it. this causes the `Bundle.main.path` to return nil

Comment: look like this..? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41775563/bundle-main-pathforresourceoftypeindirectory-returns-nil

Comment: It's highly recommended to use the URL related API anyway `Bundle.main.url(forResource: "testFile", withExtension: "rtf")`

Comment: @SureshThayu I read that thread and checked my "Copy Bundle Resources" everything's is there. What I'm confuse with is why the app works fine when I remove the "space" on the app's name? Is there some restriction of using space in the app's name?

Comment: @vadian can you add this as answer so I can accept it? it works fine!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's highly recommended to use the URL related API anyway

```
Bundle.main.url(forResource: "testFile", withExtension: "rtf")
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4.1
Its work with me to read the mp3 files in my app
Bundle.main.paths(forResourcesOfType: "mp3", inDirectory: "")