# Thread1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address = 0X48)

Tags: ios, swift4

I'm new in Swift. I am trying to Run this code but got an error:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x48) a.

Error appears here:

> **self.player.play()**

Can anyone help in this issue?

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
```

class ViewController: UIViewController {

`var player = AVAudioPlayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    do {
        if let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "music", ofType: "mp3") {
           try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath))
        }

    } catch {
        print("ERROR")
    }

    self.player.play()
}`

Comment: I think `let audiopath` or `try player` have not been succesful and then `player.play()` breaks. Is music.mp3 in the correct folder? This error may be thrown when AVAudioPlayer has nothing to be played.

Comment: Hi Miguel. It looks like truth.

guard let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "music", ofType: "mp3") else {
            print("Error 1")
            return
        }

returns an error 1. Now I'll try to get a correct path.

Answer (score 5):

What you doing with your code is:

1. Creating an instance of AVAudioPlayer **without** any data
2. Trying to create a new instance with some data from *music.mp3* file
3. Playing it

If the `audioPath` is not correct, then the player is not correctly created: application will use the one *without* valid data, leading to a crash during playback.

Your code can be written making the player `optional`, which helps preventing the crash:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var player: AVAudioPlayer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        player = initializePlayer()
        player?.play()
    }

    private func initializePlayer() -> AVAudioPlayer? {
        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "music", ofType: "mp3") else {
            return nil
        }

        return try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
    }
}
```

Some changes performed to the code:

- `player` is now *optional*: there is no need to initialize it twice. Plus if the initialization goes well you can use it without problems, otherwise your app won't crash.
- The `play` method is now in an *optional chain*
- I've moved the initialization of the player in a separate private methods, to maintain the code readable. Feel free to change it, it is just a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I've got it. The issue is that the file isn't being coping to my app bundle. To fix it:

1. Click your project
2. Click your target
3. Select Build Phases
4. Expand Copy Bundle Resources
5. Click '+' and select your file.

Thanks [Denis Hennessy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41775563/bundle-main-pathforresourceoftypeindirectory-returns-nil)